# Yammer API get/messages.json returns incomplete results

Tags: yammer

When I compare the data returned by get/messages.json to the data retrieved using the export in yammer.  get/messages.json returns 6,300 records.  The data export returns 10,469 records.  Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132853/yammer-api-missing-messages) I too am using the older_than parameter.  There was a comment in that post that suggested a rate limit issue.  I can assure you I am not exceeding the rate limit as I pause for 15 seconds after every 10 requests.

To get my incomplete 6,300 rows I...

1. Use the export API to get a list of all of the groups
2. Loop through that list of groups and download the messages for each group using `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/:group_id.json`
3. Then I use `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json` with the older_than parameter to get all of the messages in the All Company feed.

The issue appears to be with step 3.

Here is the code related to step 3 outlined above:

```
    Sub GetAllCompanyMessages()
            Try
                Console.WriteLine("Getting All Company Messages")
                If File.Exists(allCompanyPath) Then
                    'delete previous
                    If Directory.Exists(allCompanyPath) Then
                        For Each oldFile As String In Directory.GetFiles(allCompanyPath)
                            File.Delete(oldFile)
                        Next
                        Directory.Delete(allCompanyPath)
                    End If
                    'create dir
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(allCompanyPath)
                Else
                    'create dir
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(allCompanyPath)
                    'Throw New Exception("Yammer Data Export Zip Download Failed")
                End If

                'get first group of messages
                Console.WriteLine("Getting All Company Batch 1")
                Dim client As New WebClient()
                client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
                client.DownloadFile(allCompanyMessagesURL, allCompanyPath & "1.json")

                'getOlderThanID
                Dim olderThanID As Int32 = getOlderThanID(allCompanyPath & "1.json")

                'get remaining messages in batches of 20
                Dim i As Int32 = 2
                'Dim prevOlderThanID As Int32 = 0
                Dim nextOlderThanID As Int32 = olderThanID
                Do Until i = 0
                    Console.WriteLine("Getting All Company Batch " & i & " olderthanID " & nextOlderThanID)
                    client = Nothing
                    client = New WebClient()
                    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
                    client.DownloadFile(allCompanyMessagesURL & "?older_than=" & nextOlderThanID, allCompanyPath & i & ".json")
                    'prevOlderThanID = nextOlderThanID
                    nextOlderThanID = getOlderThanID(allCompanyPath & i & ".json")
                    i = i + 1
                    If nextOlderThanID = 0 Then
                        'exit loop
                        i = 0
                    End If

                    ' HANDLES 10 REQUESTS IN 10 SECONDS LIMIT
                    If i >= 10 Then
                        If i Mod 10 = 0 Then
                            ' CAUSES APP TO WAIT 15 SECONDS AFTER EVERY 10th REQUEST
                            Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for 15 seconds")
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000)
                        End If
                    End If
                Loop

                Console.WriteLine("Concatenating All Company Batches")
                Dim masterJobject As New JObject
                masterJobject = JObject.Parse("{""messages"":[]}")
                For Each path As String In Directory.GetFiles(allCompanyPath, "*.json")
                    Console.WriteLine("Concatenating All Company Batch: " & path)
                    'open each json get messages object and append
                    Dim jObj As JObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path))
                    Dim jms As New JsonMergeSettings
                    'beh 5.24.17 jms.MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
                    jms.MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat
                    masterJobject.Merge(jObj, jms)
                    'File.Delete(path)
                Next

                Console.WriteLine("Building Yammer-All-Company-Messages.json")
                File.WriteAllText(outputJSONpath & "Yammer-All-Company-Messages.json", "{ ""messages"":" & masterJobject("messages").ToString() & "}")


            Catch ex As Exception
                ErrorHandler("ERROR GetAllCompanyMessages:  " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub

Function getOlderThanID(ByVal jsonPath As String) As Int32
        Dim result As Int32 = 0
        Try
            Dim jObj As New JObject
            jObj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath))

            If CBool(jObj("meta")("older_available")) = True Then

                If Not IsNothing(jObj("messages").Last()("id")) Then
                    result = jObj("messages").Last()("id")
                End If

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler("ERROR getOlderThanID:  " & ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return result
    End Function
```

I would appreciate any insight on what the issue might be with the get/messages.json API endpoint, and how I might modify my code to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are technical limits on the number of items that will be returned from the REST API for messages. These were designed for client applications that need recent data. The best option would be use individual calls to the message endpoint from the REST API (api_url field) to fill in any gaps in your archive. Make sure everything is stored in a persistent fashion.

Comment: how do you know where the "gaps" are programatically?