# Yammer does not return every message in group

Tags: yammer

Using the following endpoint with the group id and the older_than paging parameter

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/[group_id].json?older_than=[msgid(19)]

This does not return every message in that group... it skips messages!

This is a paid network that I am testing, the API is pretty much **useless** if it does not provide all the messages. Can anyone confirm this limitation!

Comment: perhaps you'd be better off asking yammer tech support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 'older_than' parameter to try to get all messages isn't going to work:

Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/19107426/4099849

> If you attempt to iterate over messages you will hit some limits. These limits are technical in nature and you would need to revert to the search API to find much older messages. Unfortunately you will have to put up with these limitations if you are dealing with the free version of Yammer as the data export is only available with the paid version.

Assuming you're trying to do some sort of analytics, have a look at the [Yammer Data Export API](https://about.yammer.com/success/activate/admin-guide/monitoring-your-data/export-data/).

Comment: The only technical limit is the one that Yammer decides to implement, they already have request limit, so why should there be a limit on the amount of messages that you get? This is purely a Yammer policy issue, not a technical issue. I have contacted tech support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question : [Yammer API - missing messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132853/yammer-api-missing-messages/27857507#27857507)

The ansnwer is the same and his not acceptable !

When using /api/v1/messages/about_topic/ I get messages not returned by 
/api/v1/messages.json
or
/api/v1/messages/in_group

My script respect the API Rate limits and the missing messages are not older than others.
There is something wrong in the API and it must be fixed.
My company is paying for Yammer and expect a reliable API.

Comment: Good luck with that I tried to contact them multiple times only to get no reply. The issue will persist, it is a shame. Not only that they are also discontinuing the Real Time API

Comment: An alternative is to extract the messages from /api/v1/messages/about_topic/; cuz this way you get most of the missing ones.

Comment: Most but not all, plus then you have to merge every message and topic, wich mean you will waste many cycles doing something that is "stupid" when it would be so much simpler to have all the messages when you ask for them, since there are already request limits set in place, its quite simply Yammer not wanting to give you YOUR data when you ask for it.

Comment: I have open a Support Ticket on the issue. It's also discussed on Yammer Bug Group at https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/#/Threads/show?threadId=489561676

Answer (score 0):

If you want all messages inside a group,use below mentioned REST API without all parameters.Then it will list all messages present inside that particular group.

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/[group_id].json

Comment: Please read before posting. That does not work, also you will only get 20 messages using that call